# how to use logql to graph a grafana-loki time series chart with simple log file

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I have spent the past 4 hours trying to fiddle with LogQL and cannot figure out for the life how to graph this.

I have a file

```
2023-08-04T07:31:02+0000 Val: 0.1
2023-08-04T07:32:02+0000 Val: 0.2
2023-08-04T07:33:02+0000 Val: 0.3
<...more data...>
2023-08-04T51:21:02+0000 Val: 213.123123123
```

in grafana logql I have

```
{filename="/var/tmp/myfile/my.log"} |= ``
```

which generates a table... How on earth do I graph the timeseries chart with the parsed time at the start and the Val 0.1,0.2,0.3 being graphed on Y-Axis.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple method here

```
max_over_time({filename="/var/tmp/mylogs/mylog.log"} |= ``
| pattern "<_> Val: <myval>"
| unwrap myval [1m])
```

I was also able to manipulate it like this

```
max_over_time({filename="/var/tmp/mylogs/mylog.log"} |= ``
| pattern "<_> Val: <myval>"
| label_format myval="{{mulf .myval 2}}"
| unwrap myval [1m])
```

I'm still unsure how I can add a new value without overwriting one before though